# How to limit and increase download speed of res.download

Tags: express

I am making an app,using `res.download()` to download files.And I am finding a way to limit the download speed(as well as increase the download speed),is there any ways to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the `res.download()` you can't change the speed. What you can do is to limit the bandwidth of all http requests like in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57918466/12003966) (which can be done only by limiting the speed on both, client and server). You can make a use of this and limit the speed only when this requests is called and reverse it when it's done, but that will slow all requests coming when this is processed.